# Differential equation depending on a parameter, but solutions do not depend on the parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Construct an example of a differential equation depending on a parameter $a$ for which some solutions do not depend continuously on $a$.

I think that the solutions should be formed so that $a$ can be cancelled out and thus does not depend on $a$, or perhaps a differential equation that depends on $a$ but with a constant solution. I am not sure if either of these thoughts are correct, or how I would implement them if they are. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define "ODE depends on $a$". Is that dependence continuous? Is an order drop allowed while varying $a$?

Comment: @LutzL I believe the idea of the problem is that the ODE depends continuously on a but some of the solutions do not

Comment: Perhaps you can construct something where you lose the Lipschitz condition. The Picard operator has a very strong fixed point, so continuous perturbation preserving the contractivity will give a continuous fixed point.

Comment: The title does not match the question. In $$y'(x)=\cos(x)+a·(y(x)-\sin(x))$$ the solution $y(x)=\sin(x)$ does not depend on $a$. However, as every constant function, it is still continuous in $a$. 

From the general theory we know that solutions to $$y'(x)=f(x,y(x),q),\ \  y(0)=y_0(q),$$ where the functions $f$ and $y_0$ are at least Lipschitz continuous in all variables, will always depend continuously on $q$. Thus one will need something jumpy to get discontinuous variations.

Comment: It is enough to take a differential equation you know the solution of, say $f(x)$, and as LutzL did take $y'(x)=f'(x) +a(y(x)-f(x))$. You could have also $y'(x)=e^x-a(y(x)-e^x)$ or anything really.